# Burp Extension: Parsing XML/Jython

Tags: java, xml, jython, burp

I'm writing a Burp extension and need to parse some XML. Using `xml.etree.ElementTree`, I'm running into [this](https://forum.portswigger.net/thread/saxparser-dependency-delimma-499c057a) issue. Essentially:

> SAX for some reason explicitly uses thread's contextClassLoader or system classloader instead of the parent classloader.

Which results in:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXException: SAX2 driver class org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser not found
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser
```

None of the suggestions have worked for me, and I'm not sure how to resolve this. Since Burp uses a jython stand alone file, is there a way to manually inject the missing class file into the standalone `.jar`? Every way I've tried results in Burp not being able to load the python environment.

How can I parse XML within a Burp extension?